# Upgrading Symfony 2.1 to 2.2: fragment sub-framework and locale handling broken

Tags: symfony, locale, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.2

I've just upgraded from Symfony 2.1 to 2.2. I followed the instructions given here:

```
http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-2-2-0
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.2/UPGRADE-2.2.md
```

All my code was working beautifully before, but now there is some kind of problem where the framework is injecting "_fragment" into the URL after I try to do something in my application. This is changing my URL from:

```
http://server/app_dev.php/en-GB/
```

to:

```
http://server/app_dev.php/_fragment/
```

This is then being picked up as the locale by twig and causes it to fail with the following error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
("Circular reference detected when adding a fallback catalogue for locale "".")
in "/var/....../HomeBundle/Resources/views/Home/index.html.twig".

2/2 Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template 
("Circular reference detected when adding a fallback catalogue for locale "".") 
in "/var/...../HomeBundle/Resources/views/Home/index.html.twig"
1/2 LogicException: Circular reference detected when adding a fallback catalogue for locale "".
```

Part of the back trace says:

```
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelException". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException". 
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Circular reference detected when adding a fallback catalogue for locale "".") in "/var/...../HomeBundle/Resources/views/Home/index.html.twig"." at /var/...../app/cache/dev/classes.php line 6030 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
```

When I first login to the application, it all seems to be working fine, the request lists the locale as it should be:

```
_locale     "en-GB"
_route      "_home_index"
_route_params   "Array(_locale => en-GB)"
```

However, if I then click on another link (including going back to the same page), it fails with the above error and changes the request to:

```
_locale     "_fragment"
_route      "_home_index"
_route_params   "Array(_locale => _fragment)"
```

My routing (for the above example) looks like this:

```
Home_Home:
    resource:   "@HomeBundle/Controller/HomeController.php"
    type:       annotation
    prefix:     /{_locale}
    defaults:   { _locale: en }
```

My config:

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: en }
    default_locale:  en
```

I don't think the problem is the locale handling, but rather with the new fragment sub-handling framework that was added to Symfony 2.2. Possibly it is being called/activated in some way? (or I'm missing some kind of configuration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found that problem at least, simply adding a fragments configuration item in config.yml fixed that particular issue:

```
framework:
    fragments:       { path: /_fragment }
```